# ArcGIS python code to change path to relative for all subdirectories

Tags: python, path, gis, arcgis

very new to python, but have some experience with coding in university. I'm trying to find a way to change the path in every mxd file from absolute to relative as I prepare my GIS project database to transition from locally hosted to cloud hosted (just started working from home). I have found 2 snipets of code that I think might work but can't get them to work together. The code from ArcGIS only works on the one folder and I would like this to run on every subdirectory in the root. Thanks for your help!

**ArcGIS Python Portion**

```
import arcpy, os

#workspace to search for MXDs
Workspace = r"c:\Temp\MXDs"
arcpy.env.workspace = Workspace

#list map documents in folder
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")

#set relative path setting for each MXD in list.
for file in mxdList:
    #set map document to change
    filePath = os.path.join(Workspace, file)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filePath)
    #set relative paths property
    mxd.relativePaths = True
    #save map doucment change
    mxd.save()
```

**Subdirectory Code**

```
... from fnmatch import fnmatch
... 
... root = 'C:\\user\projects'
... pattern = "*.mxd"
... 
... for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
...     for name in files:
...         if fnmatch(name, pattern)
...             mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `fnmatch` module for this task. The wildcard in the `arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd')` function is sufficient. Instead of looping through the `files`, loop through the `subdirs` with `os.walk(root)`.

Try the following:

```py
import arcpy, os

root = r'C:\user\projects'
pattern = "*.mxd"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for subdir in subdirs: # loop through each subdirectory
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, subdir)
        print('Current directory: {}'.format(fullpath))
        # set new workspace to combination of path and subdir
        arcpy.env.workspace = fullpath 
        # search in the new workspace
        mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles(pattern) 
        for file in mxdList: # apply the changes for each file
            print('Processing: {}'.format(file))
            # set map document to change
            # here the variable file should be sufficient
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file) 
            # set relative paths property
            mxd.relativePaths = True
            # save map doucment change
            mxd.save()
```

Comment: This worked, however I had to change one line. was getting a runtime error on line 18. Invalid MXD filename. so I changed 
`mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file**Path**)`